# kOps 1.19 is creating 3 different instancegroups for 'nodes' instead of a single ig when creating a new cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, devops, kops

I'm recreating a cluster with kOps. Normally, on all my kops clusters, I have 3 `master` instance groups and a single `nodes` instance group. This is the default according to the docs, and what I'm used to.

However, while trying to create this cluster, it is adding the 3 master ig's, as well as 3 node ig's

```
Using cluster from kubectl context: [my-cluster]

NAME                ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX ZONES
master-us-east-1a   Master  t2.medium   1   1   us-east-1a
master-us-east-1b   Master  t2.medium   1   1   us-east-1b
master-us-east-1c   Master  t2.medium   1   1   us-east-1c
nodes-us-east-1a    Node    r5.xlarge   2   2   us-east-1a
nodes-us-east-1b    Node    r5.xlarge   2   2   us-east-1b
nodes-us-east-1c    Node    r5.xlarge   2   2   us-east-1c
```

It should look like this instead:

```
Using cluster from kubectl context: [my-cluster]

NAME                ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX ZONES
master-us-east-1a   Master  t2.medium   1   1   us-east-1a
master-us-east-1b   Master  t2.medium   1   1   us-east-1b
master-us-east-1c   Master  t2.medium   1   1   us-east-1c
nodes               Node    r5.xlarge   6   6   us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c
```

I have no idea why it's doing it this way. I've created clusters fine before using the same script. The only thing I changed is the kOps version as I updated to `v1.19`, but it doesn't mention anything obvious that would change this in the changelogs.

My create command is:

```
kops create cluster \
    --yes \
    --authorization RBAC \
    --cloud aws \
    --networking calico \
    --image ami-0affd4508a5d2481b \
    --topology private \
    --api-loadbalancer-class network \
    --vpc ${VPC_ID} \
    --subnets ${PRIVATE_SUBNETS} \
    --utility-subnets ${PUBLIC_SUBNETS} \
    --zones ${ZONES} \
    --master-zones ${ZONES} \
    --node-size ${NODE_SIZE} \
    --node-count 6 \
    --master-size ${MASTER_SIZE} \
    --state s3://${KOPS_STATE_BUCKET} \
    --ssh-public-key ${PUB_KEY_LOCATION} \
    --api-ssl-certificate ${SSL_CERT_ARN_K8S} \
    --admin-access ${API_ACCESS_CIDRS} \
    --ssh-access ${SSH_ACCESS_CIDRS} \
    ${KUBE_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

and versions

Kops: `Version 1.19.0`

Kubernetes:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-17T02:13:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:15:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

The AWS stack was generated via terraform, but I'm not sure that's related.

And yes, I can just manually create the `nodes` ig and delete these ones; but our architecture is fully scripted and I would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In kOps the default ASG layout for AWS changed from having a single node IG to one per AZ. There are multiple reasons for that:

- an incident in AWS a few years ago in a single AZ prevented scale-up of any ASG that had nodes in that AZ, essentially breaking redundancy.
- Cluster Autoscaler can better handle pods that are assigned to a given AZ. If you have ASG with multiple AZ, CAS potentially have to scale up many times before AWS decides to put the node in the desired AZ.

It is worth mentioning that `kops create cluster` is meant as an easy way of testing kOps. For production use, and especially if you are handling multiple clusters, use templates. See https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/getting_started/production/

The outcome of `kops create cluster` also changes between versions. This is one example, cilium moving from kube-proxy to eBPF nodeport service is another. If you expect repeatable outcome you must use a cluster spec/templates.